# Contar registros en una colección

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose, mongodb

Buenos días, actualmente estoy trabajando con Mongodb (Mongoose), Node.js y Express, la consulta que tengo es ¿Cómo puedo contar el número de registros que tengo en una colección?, tengo una colección que se llama perfiles y quiero saber cuantos perfiles se encuentran en ella.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método `count` de mongoose:

```
var MyCollection = dbConnection.model('MyCollection', collectionSchema);
MyCollection.count({}, function(err, count) {
    console.log( "Total: ", count);
});
```

Aquí tienes los links a la documentacion oficial:

- Modelo: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count
- Query: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count

Si echas un vistazo, verás que también se puede hacer uso de `count` con una determinada query y de este modo obtener el total de documentos encontrados para un determinado filtro.

---

## Actualización (Sept-2019)

- A partir de la versión [5.4.6 (22-01-2019)](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#546--2019-01-22) el método [`count()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) está marcado como obsoleto.
- A partir de la versión [5.2.2 (08-07-2018)](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#522--2018-07-08) se puede usar el método [`estimatedDocumentCount()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount)

Así, la consulta debería hacerse de la siguiente forma:

```
const MyCollection = dbConnection.model('MyCollection', collectionSchema);
const numOfDocs = MyCollection.estimatedDocumentCount();
```

Si se usa una función `callback` se debe hacer:

```
const MyCollection = dbConnection.model('MyCollection', collectionSchema);
MyCollection.estimatedDocumentCount((err, numOfDocs) => {
  if(err) throw(err);
  console.log(`Total: ${numOfDocs}.`);
});
```